# ASP.Net Menu sub items to load on click in place of mouseover

Tags: asp.net, menu, submenu

I have created one horizontal menu asp.net. It works fine and loads sub menu items on mouseover. But I want to load subitems on click of mouse instead of mouseover.

Below is my code and I am not able to find any property which allows user to load sub menu on click instead of mouseover.

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="Menu"
                Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="White" DataSourceID="MenuSiteMap"
                StaticPopOutImageUrl="~/images/collapsearrow.png">
                <StaticMenuItemStyle Height="40px" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="Menu" Height="40px" />
                <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="menuhover" />
                <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="menuhover" />
            </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: never thought of it anyway you can use the treeview control instead...

Comment: Found something on codeproject. Check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/114095/how-to-show-subitem-of-the-menu-on-only-clicking-t

Comment: You could use jQuery to manipulate it instead although you may need to override existing functionality already created by the Menu control.